# How is this JavaScript object somehow converted to a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I have been working on a Node.JS/MongoDB backend for a product catalogue system and I have run into a weird bug.

### The Process

First I load the product information from the product collection. This product contains information such as its name, description and also a list of file upload IDs that point to images of the product in an array of strings.
I then, for each upload ID, load the information for each photo. I then replace the array of upload ID strings with an array of file information objects. 
However, when I output the resulting product object, the list of images is a list of strings that represent JavaScript as if they were written in code.

### The Code

```
// products.controller.js
async function populateImageInformation(productRecord) {
    let imageInfo = [];
    for(let uploadId of productRecord.images) {
        let imageData = await File.getByUploadId(uploadId);
        imageInfo.push(imageData);
        console.log(typeof imageData); // => object
    }
    console.log(typeof imageInfo); // => object
    console.log(typeof imageInfo[0]); // => object
    productRecord.images = imageInfo;
    console.log(typeof productRecord.images); // => object
    console.log(typeof productRecord.images[0]); // => string
    return productRecord;
}

async function getAll(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let productRecords = await Product.find({});
        for(let productRecordI in productRecords) {
            productRecords[productRecordI] = await populateImageInformation(productRecords[productRecordI]);
        }
        res.json(productRecords);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

Mongoose schema file:

```
// file.model.js
getByUploadId: function(uploadId) {
    return this.findOne({
        uploadId
    });
}
```

I do not understand that when I set the `productRecord.images` property to `imageInfo` the values in the array suddenly become string representations of the values.
[image: weird string value]

The string does *not* contain JSON, but instead contains a human-readable string representation of how an object is hard-coded into JavaScript. These strings cannot be parsed as JSON at all. JSON expects keys to be wrapped in double quotes whereas the JavaScript code produced doesn't have this.

Is there any reason for this to happen? I have never seen this occur.

Comment: might be the case but..productRecord.images is an array of String... So might be it converting the object to string to match the types

Comment: JavaScript does not care about types, and I even tried deleting the array before setting it, but it didn't change anything

Comment: maybe res.json has side effect ? what does it do ?

Comment: `res.json` has no effect here. The data is meddled with before it is sent back to the browser.

Comment: Schema for Product is missing in the question.

Comment: @CrazyRedd i tried to make a copy of your code and updated mongoDB.. its not giving me the same problem.. can you provide more info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to **mongoose schema** , they **protect** the model by **types** you declared in **schema** . Object Returning by find is a mongoose model, they do type check when you update any value on it.

Let's come to your scenario . I have created an example . See below

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const db = require('./db');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const productSchema = new Schema({
      name: {type: String},
      images: [String]  // Note schema have array of string
    });

    const productModel = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);

    db.connect().then(() => {
      //find record from productSchema
      return productModel.find({})
        .then((productRecords) => { //productRecords - don't forget is a mongoose model object

// productRecords from db  [{"name":"gilette","images":["idx","idy"],"_id":"5ac324c4fad317265b9df226","__v":0}]


          //TRIAL A
          for (let productRecordI in productRecords) {
            productRecords[productRecordI] = populateImageInformation(productRecords[productRecordI]);

          }
          console.log(typeof productRecords[0].images[0]); //=> string;


          //SOLUTION for the problem is copy mongoose data without reference
          //TRIAL B
          productRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productRecords));
          for (let productRecordI in productRecords) {
            productRecords[productRecordI] = populateImageInformation(productRecords[productRecordI]);

          }
          console.log(typeof productRecords[0].images[0]); //=> Object;

        });

      //just a mock function change images to object
      function populateImageInformation(productRecord) {
        imageInfo = [];
        for (let uploadId of productRecord.images) {
          let imageData = {name: uploadId};
          imageInfo.push(imageData);
          console.log(typeof imageData); // => object
        }
        productRecord.images = imageInfo;
        return productRecord;
      }


    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('err', err);
    });
```